# Find local and global minimizer(s)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Consider the problem:
minimize $f(x)=x_1$ subject to
$(x_1-1)^2+x_2^2=1$, $(x_1+1)^2+x_2^2=1.$
Are there any local minimizers? Are there any global minimizers?

Is $(-2,0)$ both the local and global minimizer?

Comment: $f$ is a function of *two* variables, $x_1$ and $x_2$, even though it  depends on $x_1$ only. So minimizers, whatever they are, will be pairs of numbers, like $(x_1,x_2)=(43,-84)$.

Answer (score 1):

You constrain your function to the intersection of the circles of radius 1 centred at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$, i.e. you minimize the function f over the set $\{(0,0)\}$. Consequently, $(0,0)$ is the only local and global optimiser.

Comment: but the object function is $f(x)=x_1$. $x_1=-2$ is the minimal value of $f(x)=x_1$.